# Are there drawbacks to use Direct Debit in France, compared to paying with a credit card?

Tags: france, direct-debit

Amazon started to offer Direct Debit as a way to pay for purchases in France.

Direct Debit itself is a very common way to pay for bills in France (probably the primary one) and is well integrated with French banks. Among others, there is direct control over disputed payments (I can go to the bank web site and request the annulation of a payment - it then becomes a matter between me and the vendor, the bank will refund the money), or stop/suspend the mandate (in which case the bank will systematically refuse a payment).

I was wondering whether there are any specific advantages or inconveniences to use Direct Debit with a vendor such as Amazon (as opposed to a "supplier" such as the water company, or my ISP)